# Get remote image's exif data using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exif

How do I use Rails to get exif data from an image using the image's url?  This tool , http://exifr.rubyforge.org/, is not able to use an image's url

Comment: a possible workaround is to download an image first, then use `exifr` on it